# xml files from folder into list

Tags: python, xml, nlp, text-classification

I'm pretty new in programming and it is the first time I use xml, but for class I'm doing a gender classification project with a dataset of Blogs. 
I have a folder which consists of xml files. Now I need to make a list of names of the files there.
Then I should be able to run through the list with a loop and open each file containing XML and get out of it what I want (ex. Text and class) and then store that in another variable, like adding it to a list or dictionary.

I tried something, but it isn't right and I'm kind of stuck. Can someone help me? This is wat I have so far:

```
path ='\\Users\\name\\directory\\folder'
dir = os.listdir( path )
def select_files_in_folder(dir, ext):
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        fullname= os.path.join(path, filename)
        tree = ET.parse(fullname)
    for elem in doc.findall('gender'):
        print(elem.get('gender'), elem.text)
```

Comment: where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: can you give an example of sample output

Comment: @ponayz I just learned a bit of programming, so this is already hard for me. I'm stuck, because I'm not sure what should happen next.This code doesn't give an error, but I thought it woud create a list with the xml folders, a list I could print. Secondly, I'm not sure of the 'for elem in doc.findall'. My goal is to get the text and the classlabel, in this case gender. But I don't now for sure how to do that

Comment: @Debabrata My goal is to eventually create a jsonfile which consist of nested lists with the text and the classlabel

Comment: @Lorien you can use xmltodict module, it will give you dictionary from a xml file  
link: https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict  
Example: 
xml-file:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx  
  code:
`import json,xmltodict
data = xmltodict.parse(open('t1.xml').read())
res = map(lambda x:[x['title'], x['genre'], x['price']], data['catalog']['book'])
res = json.dumps(res)`

Comment: @Lorien well for start you just defined the function without calling it so at some point you need to execute the function `select_files_in_folder() `. From what i see you're on good track what you need to do is build the list so you need a var to hold it then you need to check that your filename is actually a xml file you could check the extension using `filename.endswith(".xml")`

Comment: @ponayz Thank you for your answer: so something like this?                    def dataset(directory):
 blogs = []
 path = '\\Users\\Lorien\\Desktop\\en\\'
 for filename in os.listdir(path):
  if filename.endswith(".xml"):   blogname= os.path.join(path, filename)
  blogname.append(directory + '/'+ blogs)
  tree = ET.parse(blogname)
    return blogs
dataset = dataset('data')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build a list of all the xml files in a given directory you can do the following

```
def get_xml_files(path):
    xml_list = []
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith(".xml"):
            xml_list.append(os.path.join(path, filename))
    return xml_list
```

just keep in mind that this is not recursive through the folders and it's just assuming that the xml files finish with .xml.

EDIT :

Parsing xml is highlly dependent of the library you'll be using. From your code I guess you're using xml.etree.ElementTree (keep in mind this lib is not safe against maliciously constructed data).

```
def get_xml_data(list):
    data = []
    for filename in list :
        root = ET.parse(filename)
        data = [ text for text in root.findall("whatever you want to get") ]
    return data
```

Comment: @ponyaz Thanks a lot for your help! Last question: now I want to iterate through that list and get the classes and text per file and put it in a different list. This list wil be my dataset.  This is what I had, but I get a str object has no atribute findall error. `def trainingdataset(list):
 for file in list_files:
  raw = open(file).read() 
  tree = ET.parse(file)
  for tree in file:
   data = []
   data.append([s.text for s in tree.findall('id'/'text'/'age_group')]) 
 return data`

Comment: well the error is saying the truth because your var tree is no longer an ET element since you did `for tree in file` which mean you iterate over the string filename